# Is urethra a part of male accessory duct system?

Tags: anatomy

In my textbook it is written that male accessory duct system constitutes the rete testis , vasa efferentia , epididymis and the vas deferens . Can urethra be also included here ?

Comment: Did you consider exploring what these other structures are accessory *to*? This line of thinking might help here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But is it because that urethra has only role in providing a comman passage for urine and sperm , but it doesn't have any role in functional maturation of spermatozoa , so it's not part of accessory duct system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really find this terminology occurring very frequently, so it seems mostly something special to your textbook and others like it. Really the primary content I find online about this particular *accessory duct* is in the form of multiple-choice homework cheat sites. For example, [this search for *"accessory duct" epididymis vas deferens* includes very few results](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C50&q=%22accessory+duct%22+epididymis+vas+deferens&btnG=) and some are false-positives.

That said, a [duct](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duct) is:

> a bodily tube or vessel especially when carrying the secretion of a gland

Accessory, in this context, has meaning along the lines of additional/supplementary/auxiliary, or *not the main/primary*, as in [the accessory duct of the pancreas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancreatic_duct). So, an "accessory duct", where the adjective "accessory" modifies "duct", is "another duct in addition to the primary/main one".

The main duct, in this case, would seem to be the urethra itself, something common with the female urogenital anatomy, whereas the male *accessory duct* is the additional ductwork needed to attach the sperm-producing testis to the outside world. So, no, if you're taking the urethra to be the *main* duct, it doesn't make sense for it to be an accessory to itself.